# Kafka - difference between Log end offset(LEO) vs High Watermark(HW)

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

What is the difference between `LEO and HW` in Replica ( `Leader Replica`)?

Will they contain the same number? I can understand HW is the `last committed message offset`.

When LEO will be updated and how?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The high watermark indicates the offset of messages that are fully replicated, while the end-of-log offset might be larger if there are newly appended records to the leader partition which are not replicated yet.

Consumers can only consume messages up to the high watermark.

See this blog post for more details: http://www.confluent.io/blog/hands-free-kafka-replication-a-lesson-in-operational-simplicity/

Comment: Thanks for the great information. Do you meant to say, the HW will be updated only the message is replicated in all the ISRs? In Asynchronous replica process also, in leader replica HW will be updated after all the ISR updated?

Comment: Both, HW and LEO are only maintained for leader partition. And yes, HW is only advanced, if ISR partitions replicated the messages.

Comment: Are you sure the HW and LEO only maintained for Leader replica? As per the wiki page https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/kafka+Detailed+Replication+Design+V3 it seems every replica has those fields..

Comment: I am not 100% sure... However, the link point to a "draft" from 2012 -- not sure if this is implemented the exact same way... If those details are important, we can dig deeper :) I can ask some colleges. The main question was about difference of EOL and HW -- and I guess the basic answer stays the same. HW is latest offset of commited messages that is replicated to IRS. EOL is was is written to partition but not replicated fully yet.

Answer (score 19):

Let's start with one of the most popular watermark definition that could be find on Google

> The high watermark is the offset of the last message that was
> successfully copied to all of the log’s replicas

I was not very well convinced of the above definition and going deeper in my research I found this nice picture:

[image: Watermark visual example]

What was wrong then? The stuck follower at the extreme right in the pic didn't have the fourth message logged.
Maybe the first definition Google found was not complete and what the author did actually intend was: "The high watermark is the offset of the last message that was successfully copied to all of the log’s ***in-sync*** replicas"

Guided by this intuition I found this [article](https://rongxinblog.wordpress.com/2016/07/29/kafka-high-watermark/) providing details about how the WM is computed together with code.

I found the WM definition reported much more precise:

> High watermark is calculated as the minimum LEO across all the ISR of this partition, and it grows monotonically.

This answer together with the code provided confirmed the intuition I had.

Summing up I think the detailed definition of the watermark shows what is the difference between LEO and WM. The latest committed offset and LEO might coincide with high water mark for in sync follower but may very well not for Leader as shown by the example in the first linked image.

Answer (score 1):

In general, your question has already been answered by the other people. I'd like to touch a few other things that are important to those two parameters.

It's not too complicated to reason about these two settings, if you only think that reading and writing will be done via the *leader* replica.

If you on the other hand know about [this one](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-392%3A+Allow+consumers+to+fetch+from+closest+replica), then things are becoming a bit more complicated, but only slightly. This KIP says that a consumer can be brought up to consume messages not only from the leader, but from a replica too.

As such, there are a few things that matter here:

- At least `HW` is tracked in each individual replica, otherwise (with that KIP in mind), you could consume messages that are ahead of other replicas, and have not yet been replicated.
- One more reason of why `HW` is tracked on each replica is important when you think about the case that one replica goes down and another one is elected as leader. What should the value of `LEO` be? Latest `HW` would be a perfect use-case.
- One more interesting thing is what happens when you connect your consumer to a replica that is part of replication factor, but not as part of `min.insync`. When you produce a message, the message will be replicated *sync* in `min.insync` replicas, and *async* in the ones part of replication factor. (Think that `A, B` = min insync and `A,B,C` = replication factor 3). In this case the producer can successfully write to `A` and `B` and report that the message has been written, while your consumer that is attached to `C` can see it only later, when `HW` is updated.